# How to optimize CASE statement in SELECT query which has same check condition for three different columns

Tags: oracle10g

I have below select statement to fetch the data having CASE statement.

```
SELECT  PK_ID
,MGR_ID
,EMP_ID 
,CASE
    WHEN msts.MGR_ID is null AND msts.EMP_ID is not null THEN
        (SELECT 'A' from dual)  
    ELSE
        (SELECT 'B' from dual)  
END FIRST_COL
,CASE
    WHEN msts.MGR_ID is null AND msts.EMP_ID is not null THEN
        (SELECT 'P' from dual)   
    ELSE
        (SELECT 'Q' from dual)
END SECOND_COL
,CASE
    WHEN msts.MGR_ID is null AND msts.EMP_ID is not null THEN
        (SELECT 'X' from dual)
    ELIE
        (SELECT 'Y' from dual)
END THIRID_COL
 from m_sel_tabs msts
```

here, As i know that we can check condition with mulitiple columns but the result will be only one for CASE statement.

so my question is here that as my check CASE statement is the same for all three columns (FIRST_COL, SECOND_COL, THIRID_COL), hence is there any other way to write this query in an optimized way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by 'optimised' here - just less repetition? (And why are you selecting the string literals from dual?)

Comment: Yes, just less repetition. (in this exam I have selected )

And why are you selecting the string literals from dual? --> I have used string literals from dual just for example.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm wrong, but - when saying that you have "the same 3 CASE statements" - well, you don't. Those are 3 *different* CASE statements. An expression is the same, yes, but you're selecting 3 different columns, with different results (A, B, P, Q, X, Y - in your example).

You could create a function which would "hide" code you currently use and make the `SELECT` prettier, such as

```
select 
  pk_id, ...,
  f_col(1, MGR_ID, EMP_ID) first_col,
  f_col(2, MGR_ID, EMP_ID) second_col,
  f_col(3, MGR_ID, EMP_ID) third_col
from m_sel_tabs
```

but - at the end - it would be just the same (or, possibly somewhat *worse* because of context switching) as you'd have to put all that code somewhere (into the function, right?).

Comment: @Littlefoot- Yes, we need to keep the function somewhere and which will be again context switching for the other developer.

Comment: Ah! Sorry; just in case you didn't understand what I meant to say - I think that query you currently have is OK.